# Change the link of a download in Downthemall

Tags: download

Suppose I am downloading a file with DownThemAll!, but the link becomes broken. Suppose that I know of a link to another location  where the same file is hosted. Is there a way that I can tell DownThemAll! to use the new link, so I can resume the download (without having to start the download from the beginning)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried, but I guess you can add *Mirror links* in your downloads which enables the download manager to download from multiple locations listed in *Mirror Links*

To add Mirror, just open the `Download Information` dialog and in  `Options` tab you will see `Mirrors` , click on `Manage Download Mirrors` and Add the Desired link in the List.